# Undefined symbol when installing R package

Tags: r, bioconductor

So probably this is some odd setting I've added, but removing my `.Renviron`/`.Rprofile`/`~/.R/Makevars` don't seem to help. Grateful for any suggestions on how to debug.

`BiocManager::install("DropletUtils")` leads to this error (normal output up to this point omitted):

```
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘DropletUtils’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/alan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/00LOCK-DropletUtils/00new/DropletUtils/libs/DropletUtils.so':
  /home/alan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/00LOCK-DropletUtils/00new/DropletUtils/libs/DropletUtils.so: undefined symbol: __ubsan_vptr_type_cache
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
```

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblasp-r0.2.20.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] BiocManager_1.30.12 compiler_4.0.5      tools_4.0.5        
[4] parallel_4.0.5
```

Comment: try to manually remove this folder "/home/alan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/00LOCK-DropletUtils" and try to install again

Comment: That folder doesn't exist; if that were the issue then the error message would reference being unable to remove it.

Comment: Reinstalling all the dependencies magically fixed it.